# How to publish a Powershell Module to PowershellGallery with Appveyor?

Tags: powershell, github, appveyor

Is there a way to add a custom powershell script into the appveyor build script to publish a module to powershellgallery? - The module source would be in the github repo.

If not, maybe it's possible within the appveyor web config itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can create script based [Publish-Module command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/powershellget/publish-module) and insert it into right stage of [build pipeline](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#build-pipeline). For example if you decide to publish after test stage, it will look like this in YAML:

`after_test:
- ps: Publish-Module -Name "MyDscModule" -NuGetApiKey "11e4b435-6cb4-4bf7-8611-5162ed75eb73"`

Or in UI you need to go to **Settings > Test > Auto > After tests script > PS** and enter publish script.